# Finding the last point in code where app executed before crashing somewhere in Androids OS world?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm finding Eclipse unlike virtually every environment I've worked in thusfar does not actually show me the last point in which my code crashed on Android, instead it takes me to something in an android.jar file to which it has no sourcecode access, logcat shows me absolutely nothing besides the fact the app crashed os it's no help either, the call stack under the 'debug' panel (if it's actually a callstack) shows what basically amounts to gibberish.

In XCode, Visual Studio, MonoDevelop and others it's very easy to traceback any exception or crash thrown back to the source in your code.

Is there an option to do the same with Eclipse?

Comment: The stacktrace of the exception in the Logcat points to the last line  where the code crashed(the last line before the line with the exception's name). offtopic: why did you deleted the question with the editor listener?

Comment: Hi Luksprog, sorry I thought the question wasn't well thought out enough and therefore not appropriate for stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1):

When figuring out what went wrong reading Java Exceptions, the first couple of lines would point you to the part of your code that caused the problem. Having that said, you can download the Android SDK source code and point to it in Eclipse whenever you open an Android class, which will help you see the actual source code at that line as opposed to bytecodes.